# Calculate installments on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, script

i try to calculate each installment price on product page through php and html.
 I have add this code but php cannot take the value ($doseis) to calculate it:

```
<?php 
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$price = $_product->getFinalPrice(); 
?>
<?php if ($price >=150) { echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('doseisproduct')->toHtml(); }?>
<?php echo "calculate installment" ?>

<select method="post" action="" name="doseis" size="1" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<?php 
$doseis = $_POST[doseis];
$_SESSION['doseis'] = $doseis;
echo $doseis;
$installment = (($price) / ($doseis)) ;
?>
<?php echo $installment; ?></div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $price = $_product->getFinalPrice(); 
    if ($price >= 150) { 
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('doseisproduct')->toHtml(); 
    }
    echo "calculate installment";
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="test"> 
<select name="doseis" size="1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<?php 
    $doseis = $_POST['doseis'];
    $_SESSION['doseis'] = $doseis;
    echo $doseis;
    $installment = (($price) / ($doseis));
    echo $installment; 
?>
```

Comment: With int() it doesn't work. With action i have not changes.

Comment: please try my updated code

Comment: I have already try to get a submit button, when submit is clicked it add the product to cart and drives to cart page. I search for a solution with html... maybe it is better to add this calculaton to a static block

Comment: That because your code is inside Add To Cart form. Please put it outside of that form and it will work